# Tabula font warnings result in table not getting parsed from document. Is this how it is supposed to work?

Tags: tabula-py

I parsed 3 documents to fetch tables. The results as follow:

1. Document 1: Perfect parsing.
2. Document 2: got Jul 16, 2019 5:25:42 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font 
   WARNING: Using fallback font NimbusSanL-Bold for Univers-Bold
   Not sure if this is related but the second page was parsed and the first one was not.
3. Document 3: Got Jul 17, 2019 10:21:25 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font 
   WARNING: Using fallback font NimbusSanL-Regu for Univers. Nothing was parsed from this one.

These are the current tabula parsing settings:

```
     rows = tabula.read_pdf(filename,
                       pages='all',
                       silent=True,
                       pandas_options={
                           'header': None,
                           'error_bad_lines': False,
                           'warn_bad_lines': False
                       })
```

Are there other settings that might solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings came from PDFBox which is depended by tabula-java. Unfortunately, the problem itself comes from PDF itself and no way to workaround with tabula-py.